# xmlstarlet - extracting Salesforce data for controlled fields

Tags: salesforce, xmlstarlet

I'm looking for a way to extract data from Salesforce config dump for controlled fields. Dump is XML file, where I have following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<valueSet>
    <valueSettings>
        <controllingFieldValue>Product A</controllingFieldValue>
        <controllingFieldValue>Product B</controllingFieldValue>
        <valueName>1</valueName>
    </valueSettings>
    <valueSettings>
        <controllingFieldValue>Product A</controllingFieldValue>
        <valueName>2</valueName>
    </valueSettings>
</valueSet>
```

It means:

- for 'Product A' and 'Product B' value 1 is allowed;

  for 'Product A' value 2 is allowed.

So for 'Product A' value 1 and 2 is allowed.
For 'Product B' only value 1 is allowed.

I would like to create list of allowed values per product.
I'm trying with this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//valueSettings' -i 'controllingFieldValue[text()="Product A"]' -v 'controllingFieldValue[text()]' -o '|' -v 'valueName[text()]' -n test.xml
```

Output is:

```
Product A
Product B|1
Product A|2
```

So also other `controllingFieldValue` are displayed for `valueSettings` node, where matching `controllingFieldValue` was found.

How to display only `controllingFieldValue` matching criteria with corresponding `valueName`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get proper result using:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//valueSettings' -i 'controllingFieldValue[text()="Product A"]' -v 'controllingFieldValue[text()="Product A"]' -o '|' -v 'valueName[text()]' -n test.xml
```

Output is:

```
Product A|1
Product A|2
```

Comment: One more approach: `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//valueSettings/controllingFieldValue[text()="Product A"]' -v 'text()' -o '|' -v '../valueName[text()]' -n test.xml`